# How to fix for loop in Python Visio Converter

Tags: python, excel, winapi, visio, win32com

I am trying to run a for loop but have it stop when it gets to a certain date, and it does this, however, it prints out multiple shapes on top of each other, when I only want 1. The program somehow prints the number of shapes based on the row number it is in Excel. Not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as vis
app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch( 'Visio.Application' )

current = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet3.cell_value(7,9), wb.datemode))
currentDate = current.strftime('%m/%d')
dateList = []
for row in range(1,sheet3.nrows):
    if sheet3.cell_value(row,13) == "":
        continue
    date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet3.cell_value(row,13), wb.datemode))
    dateList.append(date.strftime('%m/%d'))
    for date in dateList:
        x1 = sheet3.cell_value(row,14)
        x2 = sheet3.cell_value(row,15)
        y1 = sheet3.cell_value(row,16)
        y2 = sheet3.cell_value(row,17)
        borderColor = 0
        borderType = 0
        colorValue = sheet3.cell_value(9,10)
        colorFunc(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        shape.Cells('FillforegndTrans').FormulaU = sheet3.cell_value(7,10)
    if currentDate == date:
        break
```

Comment: You are using `date` for 2 different things: the date you get from a cell, and as the index variables in a loop.  Since you are using this same variable to determine when to `break` the loop, this may be the issue.

Comment: I don't think so, I just tried it using a different variable and the same thing happens again.

Comment: Where is the printing happening?

Comment: The printing of the shapes is happening in Microsoft Visio. The shapes are rectangles, which come from colorFunc(x1,y1,x2,y2). (This function is rather long, so I did not post it, but the problem does not occur with this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Instead of having a for loop, I need to just state at the end an if statement, if the currentDate is in the dateList, then break.

```
dateList = []
for row in range(1,sheet3.nrows):
    if sheet3.cell_value(row,13) == "":
        continue
    date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet3.cell_value(row,13), wb.datemode))
    dateList.append(date.strftime('%m/%d'))
    current = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(sheet3.cell_value(7,9), wb.datemode))
    currentDate = current.strftime('%m/%d')
    x1 = sheet3.cell_value(row,14)
    x2 = sheet3.cell_value(row,15)
    y1 = sheet3.cell_value(row,16)
    y2 = sheet3.cell_value(row,17)
    borderColor = 0
    borderType = 0
    colorValue = sheet3.cell_value(9,10)
    colorFunc(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    shape.Cells('FillforegndTrans').FormulaU = sheet3.cell_value(7,10)
    if currentDate in dateList:
        break
```